# htaccess not working perfectly

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On my website I write blogs which populate following kind of links

```
http://example.com/blog.php?article=article-title-goes-here
```

I used the following htaccess code to have pretty urls with htaccess but half of the code not working

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule blog/article/(.*)/ blog.php?article=$1
RewriteRule blog/article/(.*) blog.php?article=$1
```

The website is being redirected to www.example.com but it does not effects the blog url

EDIT : When I entered the url

http://asinnetworks.com/blog/article/Hackers-take-over-Israel-army-Twitter-account/

which was previously

http://asinnetworks.com/blog.php?article=Hackers-take-over-Israel-army-Twitter-account

the page loads but does not loads css and stuff

Comment: Show an example of the requested URL and the current result and the desired result.

Comment: Are you entering URL as `http://example.com/blog/article/article-title-goes-here` ?

Comment: @anubhava updated the original post

Comment: Note: Instead of matching twice (with and without forward slash) you can just make the last forward slash optional (i.e. `.../?`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

**Or else**

You can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />`

**Or else** add this rewrite rule just below `www` forcing rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^article/(.+?\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js))$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule blog/article/([^/]+)/?$ blog.php?article=$1 [L,QSA]
```